# How to sum from a list of reference in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a list of reference in Excel the content of which I want to sum up.
How would I do that ?

Let say I want to sum up the content of B1 and C2 using the list in A1:A2 ? so I get the result 11 ?

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B1 | 8 | 0 |
| 2 | C2 | 0 | 3 |

=sum(indirect(A1:A2)) ??

hum... find my answer asking the question ! Somehow that is working.

Comment: Yes it works in various ways, you can refer the answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1&":"&A2))
```

or,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(A1&":"&A2))
```

[image: SUM_FROM_LIST_OF_REFERENCE]